# Index formula to return blank cell as a blank not 0

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I am using the below formula to copy values from a spreadsheet to another.

`=IF(ROWS(J$3:J5)>$E$1,"",INDEX('People Forecast'!J$3:J$290,SMALL(IF(Table1[Project]=$B$1,ROW(Table1[Project])-ROW('People Forecast'!$H$3)+1),ROWS((J$3:J5)))))`

This code returns blank cells as a 0 instead of returning as blank. Is there a way to fix this, so that it returns just a blank value? (I am unsure where to put the if statement to check for blanks and the range required)

Answer (score 0):

This reads as if the output is 0, make it blank, otherwise proceed:

`=IF(IF(ROWS(J$3:J5)>$E$1,"",INDEX('People Forecast'!J$3:J$290,SMALL(IF(Table1[Project]=$B$1,ROW(Table1[Project])-ROW('People Forecast'!$H$3)+1),ROWS((J$3:J5)))))=0,"",IF(ROWS(J$3:J5)>$E$1,"",INDEX('People Forecast'!J$3:J$290,SMALL(IF(Table1[Project]=$B$1,ROW(Table1[Project])-ROW('People Forecast'!$H$3)+1),ROWS((J$3:J5))))))`